# save docker output to a text file

Tags: docker

I can download the image that has sqlite database built-in.

```
docker run --rm -it shantanuo/panama sqlite3 panama.sqlite
```

I get the prompt where I can type sql command and get the results.

`sqlite> select * from panama limit 10;`

Can I do this without initiating a container? something like this does not work...

```
echo "select * from panama limit 10;" | docker run --rm shantanuo/panama sqlite3 panama.sqlite > stn.txt
```

Comment: Add your Dockerfile to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desired behavior doing that:

```
docker run --rm shantanuo/panama sqlite3 panama.sqlite "select * from panama limit 10" > stn.txt
```